# Excel - import data from an online xls file daily

Tags: excel, import

How do I import data from an online `.xls` file online (such as http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/hist-exchange-rates/2010-2013.xls) into Excel? I can't use the "From Web" data connection. I have access to Access if that is more appropriate.

Alternately, how can I use the data from a daily updated webpage and have it save the table with the date every time (instead of overwriting previous days' records)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried something as simple as:

```
Sub OpenXLSfromURL()
Dim wbMe As Workbook
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim w As Integer 
Dim wbURL As Workbook
Dim url As String

Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook
url = "http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/hist-exchange-rates/2010-2013.xls"
Set wbURL = Workbooks.Open(url)

'## Add code to copy this data to your workbook and/or manipulate the data...'
w = wbMe.Sheets.Count

'## Add a new worksheet to the end of ThisWorkbook:'
Set wsNew = wbMe.Sheets.Add(After:=wbMe.Sheets(w))

'## Copy & Paste this data in to our new worksheet:'
wbURL.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A1")

'## Close the downloaded version which we no longer need:'
wbURL.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: OK. This is almost the answer. If I leave out the last line, I get the file downloaded. If I want to import this data into an existing sheet, how would I do that? My thought was to use `Set wsNew = Sheets("RBA Data")`

Comment: @Hugh that's correct, you can `Set wsNew = Sheets("Any sheet name")` and that will set the destination sheet to an existing sheet.

Comment: Unforutunately, I get the error "Subscript out of range". Your solution seems to open a new workbook (which doesn't have the sheet), whereas I want the data imported to an existing sheet in the current workbook.

Comment: @Hugh You have already identified the source of this problem  -- `wsNew` does not contain the sheet `"RBA Data"`.  There are two `Workbook` variables in this code. One of them is `wsNew`, which is used in the `...Destination:= wsNew.Range...` part of the `Copy` statement.  I think you will be able to figure out how to fix that so it refers to the other `Workbook` variable, `wbMe`. :)

Comment: For those playing at home `wbURL.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=wbMe.Sheets("RBA").Range("A1")`

I also used `ActiveWorkbook` to avoid some esoteric errors.