# Excel - import data from an online xls file

Tags: excel, import, import-from-excel, vba

I am trying to get the data from an Excel that is found online to a sheet on my computer. I have tried the script from this post ([Excel - import data from an online xls file daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269422/excel-import-data-from-an-online-xls-file-daily?newreg=f3dcb95fa8c34df4a22df93c1a6e549c) ), but I would like to get the data in the same sheet, instead of creating a new sheet/having a new workbook open whenever I want to run the macro.

I have tried replacing this line:

```
Set wsNew = wbMe.Sheets.Add(After:=wbMe.Sheets(w))
```

with: `Set wsNew = wbMe.Sheets("Sheet9")`

This way, tried to have the sheet9 always updated, instead of opening a new worksheet everytime I run the macro.

The full VBA code that I used was:

```
Sub OpenXLSfromURL()
Dim wbMe As Workbook
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim w As Integer
Dim wbURL As Workbook
Dim url As String

Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook
url = "https://google.com/test.xls"
Set wbURL = Workbooks.Open(url)

'## Add code to copy this data to your workbook and/or manipulate the data...'
w = wbMe.Sheets.Count

'## Add a new worksheet to the end of ThisWorkbook:'
Set wsNew = wbMe.Sheets(Sheet9)

'## Copy & Paste this data in to our new worksheet:'
wbURL.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A1")

'## Close the downloaded version which we no longer need:'
wbURL.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please keep in mind this is not a code service, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I have made the changes, would that suffice?

Comment: There is still no specific problem or error or a clear desired behavior. Where do you exactly want your data, do you want to add your data exactly for example. You've simply copied the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16270208/5661165) and tried the first comment. Do a little research!